# AbortController signal for Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using a AbortController to cancel Promises in my React project. However, the problem is that my routing do not refresh the website, rather it renders components. Therefore the signal of the AbortController is stuck in true after the first time I use controller.abort().

So in my service file, I'm doing the following:

```
export const controller = new AbortController();
let signal = controller.signal;

export const getPersons = () => {
   fetch(something, {signal}).then(...)
}

export const getAnimals = () => {
   fetch(something, {signal}).then(...)
}
```

Then I use the controller in another file, let's call it Animals:

```
import {getAnimals, controller} from "..."

const Animals = () => {
   controller.abort();
   getAnimals(...);
}
```

So `getUsers()` takes a long time to fetch, I want to switch to `getAnimals()` and cancel all other promises except for the one I want. The problem is when I want to use `getUsers()`, the signal is already aborted and nothing is being fetched if the website is not refreshed.

Don't ask me why I want to get animals if the list of persons are too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you shouldn't reuse `AbortController`

Instead create new instance per request/requests ( if you want to abort them all )

Then they can be aborted when component unmounts.

```js
const getAnimals = () => {
   const controller = new AbortController();
   const promise = fetch(something, {signal: controller.signal})
   return [promise, controller];
}
```

Comment: I cannot get it to work... Here is an example of ish what I'm doing: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tTWwZxhdwn/

Comment: TrackPromise is just an import to get a loading spinner, so don't mind that.

Answer (score 0):

I have now tried with axios instead of fetch, and it is much easier to handle. You can pass a cancelationToken to the service and it will cancel if the component unmounts.